# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGfRu.png)If i use ` :   its working fine in Chrome browser but not working IE, if i removed and tried using ' or " getting invalid or unexpected error, please help me on this.

```
jQuery('label.common-label').each(function(item){
    let obj = this;
    let color = jQuery(obj).css('background-color');
    let classList = jQuery(obj).attr('class').split(' ');
    let str = '';
    for(var i=0; i < classList.length; i++) {
        str += '.' + classList[i];
    }

    str = 'label' + str + '::before';
    let str1 = '.active-facet ' + str;

    console.log(color);
    let styleList = '<style>
    ${str}{
        border-color: ${color} !important;
    }
    ${str1}{
        background-color: ${color} !important;
    }

</style>';
    jQuery(obj).parent().append(styleList);
});
```

Comment: The first problem you have is that IE doesn't support template literals surrounded by backticks `\``. The second is that those multiline strings are not syntactically correct.

Comment: If you want to support ie, you have to use string concatenation for example: `let styleList = '<style>' + ` then next line `'${str} {'`

Comment: Thanks for response @peter : i tried using this but unexpected token error

let styleList = '<style>' +
    '${str}{
        'border-color: ${color} !important;'
    }
    '${str1}{
        'background-color: ${color} !important;'
    }

'</style>'

Comment: Thanks For your Quick response @Peter : same error in chrome, **unexpected token < **

Comment: Yeah, sorry I had a typo at the last `<style>`. https://jsbin.com/fevalujuro/1/edit?js,console this  will work if jQuery is defined.

Comment: Thanks @peter : Working fine but in html its showing like string variable
<style>${str}{border-color: ${color} !important;}${str1}{background-color: ${color} !important;}</style>

Comment: If you are not using template literals, `'${str}{' +` should be `str + '{' +`

Comment: Thank you very much @peter working fine as expected :)